# Primefaces 3.3.1 <p:editor not visible if used with <p:inplace after using cancel/save buttons

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces, inline, rich-text-editor

primefaces richtext editor inline visibility glitch:

If the commandButton "Open/Clear" (which is meant just to clear the editor values in the bean) is clicked then the editor becomes visible again.

```
 <div id="multilanguage-descriptions">
   <p:inplace  styleClass="ui-multilanguage-description"
       id="ajaxInplace" widgetVar="inplaceeditorWidget" editor="true"
       toggleable="true" label="Edit" effect="slide" effectSpeed="fast">
 <p:editor  widgetVar="editorWidget" rendered="true"
       id="editor"  value="#{editorBean.value}" width="600"/>
  <p:commandButton  process="@this"
       ajax="true" value="Open/Clear" update="editor"
       id="clearButton"  action="#{editorBean.clearValue()}"/>

 </p:inplace>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed your post, use the {} code format button to have it display correctly.

Comment: Is the value attribute of your editor component correct or is this just a typo when putting the code in your question?  It should be `#{editorBean.value}`

Comment: HiYes it was a typo... I am struggling with the editor to post questions here too :)

Comment: This is the code:  <p:editor  widgetVar="editorWidget" rendered="true" id="editor" value="#{editorBean.value}" width="600"/>

Answer (score 1):

Since I came across the same problem and since I had nothing else to do with my day (yes it took me a full day) I figured it out (at least for me).

The problem lies in the container (the inplace element) of the editor being updated. This causes an update to occur on the editor element. The editor has one big con and that is that it's size is 'hard coded' at render time. Since the editor is hidden when the update occurs the editor isn't rendered correctly.

I've created an example to demonstrate the problem:

```
<h:head>
</h:head>
<body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton onclick="inplace.show()" icon="ui-icon-pencil" value="edit"/>
        <p:inplace widgetVar="inplace" >
            <p:editor id="editor"/>
            <p:commandButton onclick="inplace.cancel()" icon="ui-icon-cancel"
                value="cancel" />
            <p:commandButton onclick="inplace.save()" icon="ui-icon-disk" value="save" />
        </p:inplace>
    </h:form>
</body>
```

When you run this example you can click on the edit button and the thing works as expected. However if you click the cancel button (update occurs) and then click on edit again, the editor isn't shown.

The 'solution' is to force an update to the editor. In the example you can do this by adding an update to the edit button:

```
<p:commandButton onclick="inplace.show()" icon="ui-icon-pencil" value="edit" update="editor"/>
```

There is a slight delay when showing the editor because of the update, but hey it's better then no editor at all.